# Google Play Console - Android app suported by 0 devices

Tags: android, installation, google-play, google-play-console

I'm having trouble setting up my android app in Google Play Console.
After uploading the apk I see "Supported Android devices - 0 devices".

Here is the Manifest

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="xxxxxx">

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxxxxx"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:supportsRtl="false"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                    <activity
                        android:name=".SplashActivity"
                        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>

            </manifest>
```

Here is the gradle setup

```
                apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "xxxxxxxxxx"
                    minSdkVersion 23
                    targetSdkVersion 26
                    versionCode 5
                    versionName "1.0.1"
                    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
                }
                lintOptions {
                    checkReleaseBuilds false
                    abortOnError false
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled true
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
                })
                implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
                implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
                implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'
                compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
                compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
                implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
                testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

                compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
                annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
            }
```

And this is what I get in Google Play Console
[image]

The app was already tested on a few devices.

I see this is a common problem but most of the questions I've found are related to the permission for camera.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related commons.io package and it had to be changed to:

compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

Comment: feel free to approve your own answer, for the question to be marked as solved (you just won't get points)